# Getting cmd results in Java

Tags: java, cmd

im writing a simple programming environment in java for the programming language haskell. As a feature I want to get the Haskell compiler results displayed in my java program. You can compile Haskell files in the cmd with the command "ghci haskellfile.hs" of course only if you have an installed haskell compiler.

But I got a problem: Here's my code for getting the Haskell compiler results from the cmd.

```
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","ghci haskellfile.hs");
            Process p = pb.start();
            InputStream out = p.getInputStream();

            int i=0;
            String output = "";

            while(i!=-1){
                output += (char) i;
                i = out.read();
            }

            System.out.println(output);
```

It works perfectly for commands like "dir" or other cmd commands but when I try it with "ghci haskellfile.hs" the java program freezes and no output is displayed. 
Do you know whats the reason for that and how to fix it?

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: What happens when you run in a command prompt window `ghci haskellfile.hs`? Does it work or is the Glasgow Haskell Compiler waiting for input from __stdin__ for completion of compilation? And are you sure that the file `haskellfile.hs` is in the directory which is the current directory on running `cmd.exe` from within your Java application? And are you sure that `ghci` without file extension and without full path is found out all by Windows command interpreter?

Comment: SO when I run 'ghci haskellfile.hs' in the cmd the results remain in the same cmd tab. But the command promt changes to the Haskell command prompt. It gives the compiling results of haskellfile.hs and waits for input. You can execute all Haskell functions but no cmd commands in this prompt.

Comment: Well, I suggest that you read the documentation of Glasgow Haskell Compiler, especially the section about command line options, and find out which options to use to compile a Haskell source file without any further user interaction. I don't know anything about ghci, but all compilers I have ever worked with are executed usually with several parameters for complete compilation without any further user input with results written to __stdout__ and errors and warnings written to __stderr__ returning with exit code 0 on success and a greater value on errors.